# jQuery POST Parameter disassembles TypeScript constructor field / property

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I basically use the `jQuery.post` method to make a request to the server with some additional object parameter. jQuery now internally disassembles the object to get some sort of JSON out of it for the actual request. Works pretty sweet, but I encountered, that it causes a problem if I have declared a constructor in my TypeScript class (with some inheritance involved): jQuery now tries to call that method 'constructor' during its object disassemble-process, which causes some ugly side-effects on my side including undefinition of functions (Additionally to the side-effects it would be nice, if there is no POST-Parameter called 'constructor' as it is not part of the actual request data).

Is there any nice way to actually prevent jQuery from parsing the 'constructor' method of my parameter object?

Comment: I am doubtful that this is what's actually happening. jQuery is most likely just calling `JSON.stringify` on your object and wouldn't be calling any constructors. Can you post details about your object? Maybe the object contains cycles, which makes generating JSON impossible.

Comment: Nope it doesn't use `JSON.stringify` (started a debugging session to see whats really behind it) - some excerpt:
`jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) { ...
// If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );`

Comment: I have made a little [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt8z3q7z/) out of a simple TypeSript class inheritance sample on the playground - You'll see that there is a POST-Param called 'constructor'